# how to get gradle nebula lint plugin to work with Gradle 6?

Tags: gradle, lint, gradle-plugin

The documentation is not clear on what version of the plugin works with what version of gradle, or what exact command to run.

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.lint

Note: I'm posting a self answer shortly so no need to close this as too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to have changed after version 17. This should work, I tested it:

#### build.gradle

```
 plugins {
    id("nebula.lint") version "17.0.0"
 }

 gradleLint.rules = ['unused-dependency']
```

#### Command

```
gradle-6.8.1/bin/gradle autoLintGradle
```

#### Example output

```
> Task :autoLintGradle

This project contains lint violations. A complete listing of the violations follows.
Because none were serious, the build's overall status was unaffected.

..............



warning   unused-dependency                  this dependency should be removed since its artifact is empty (no auto-fix available)
build.gradle:77
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.6.6'

✖ 30 problems (0 errors, 30 warnings)

To apply fixes automatically, run fixGradleLint, review, and commit the changes.
```

### Other notes

#### nebula lint plugin version 17.X

```
gradle lint
gradle lintGradle
gradle autoLintGradle
```

#### nebula lint plugin version 18.X

(No idea, will fill it in if I ever discover!)

#### Multi-module projects

I haven't figured out how to get it to work on one yet. Only a simple project.